# counting the number of occurences in a file of data list

Tags: shell, text-processing, statistics

I have a data file, like

```
7
2
10
9
10
3
2
4
2
4
6
```

Each line has a single value. I want to count the occurence of each value. For instance, 10 occurs two times in this file.

Is there a simple way to do that under linux without writing formal counting program?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
$ sort -n file | uniq -c
```

Where `-n` enables numeric sorting and `-c` enables counting.

For the above sequence:

```
$ echo -e '7\n2\n10\n9\n10\n3\n2\n4\n2\n4\n6' | sort -n | uniq -c 
  3 2
  1 3
  2 4
  1 6
  1 7
  1 9
  2 10
```

(The first columns contains the counts, the 2nd the numbers.)

Comment: +1 a more readable way to write that echo statement is `printf "%s\n" 7 2 10 9 10 3 2 4 2 4 6`

Comment: Thanks, I did not know `uniq` has a `-c` switch